# 2 monitors (DVI-D, HDMI) one card (Radeon Rx 480) only DVI-D is detected

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, amdgpu, dvi

I've installed today Ubuntu on my USB.

I'm having troubles with my configuration (DVI-D, HDMI), that **works fine on windows 10**.

Using 'xrandr':

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94
```

Somehow the **HDMI is disconnected**. This problem does not replicate when using windows 10.

Could it be a driver issue?
I've heard that Ubuntu comes with an AMD driver-pro, so my question here is:

**Do I need to install a different AMD driver than the one Ubuntu comes out with?**

My graphic card is an AMD Radeon Rx 480 8gb.

Thanks for taking time reading and, possibly, responding. Have a nice day.

Comment: Installing the latest AMD GPU driver is a good start. Check out the docs [here](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll install them, but my question is, will there be any problem when using this USB OS on a machine without a specific card? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Obuz There is no driver for Ubuntu 20.04... I'll have to wait. Been new I did not know it was released 25 days ago :D